# Strange freeze when loading IntelliJ IDEA Editor

Tags: gnome, java, kde, freeze, intellij

Since about three weeks IntelliJ is freezing when I'm trying to load any project. It's the same with a new project too. 
It seems like it freezes the whole xserver - I can't interact with any application until I kill the java process in the terminal.

Currently I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 (tried it with Kubuntu 15.04 too) and IntelliJ 14.1.4.

**What have I checked already?**

- Several log files (IntelliJ Log, syslog) - There is nothing about the error
- Console output of IntelliJ - nothing too

**What have I tried already?**

- New, raw installation of IntelliJ (same problem)
- Reinstall the operating system (it worked until the first reboot after the installation of IntelliJ)
- Different Java versions (Oracle/OpenJDK, JDK7/8) (same problem)
- Other desktop environment (Gnome, KDE Plasma) (same problem)
- Change some JVM args (related to RAM) (not working)
- Run IntelliJ as root (not working)

Maybe an additional interesting piece of information is that this error first occured after I changed my mainboard, CPU and RAM. However, IntelliJ on Linux is the only program with troubles - so I hardly believe that the reason of the problem is the change of the hardware.

**Output of free -m**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15943       5518      10424        100        704       2541
-/+ buffers/cache:       2272      13670
Swap:         8192          0       8192
```

Comment: Add the output of `free -m`.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 I added it to the post.

Comment: This seems to be the same problem, the "workaround" to use taskset 0x80 ./idea.sh works, but IDEA is very slow: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278238

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced a similar freezing issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4 (162.2032.8) on Ubuntu 16.04.1 (64-bit) when importing a project.

JetBrains support suggested the following work-around:

Before the UI becomes unresponsive change from "Packages" to "Project" view.

That allowed me to proceed past the freezing.

The support referenced this unresolved issue from 2008 regarding this behavior: [IDEA-18765 Slow synchronous package view tree update](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-18765)